# How to collect two fields of an object into the same list?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an Object of goods, which has two properties: `firstCategoryId` and `secondCategoryId`. I have a list of goods, and I want to get all category Ids (including both firstCategoryId and secondCategoryId).

My current solution is:

```
List<Integer> categoryIdList = goodsList.stream().map(g->g.getFirstCategoryId()).collect(toList());
categoryIdList.addAll(goodsList.stream().map(g->g.getSecondCategoryId()).collect(toList()));
```

Is there a more convenient manner I could get all the categoryIds in a single statement?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it with a single `Stream` pipeline using `flatMap` :

```
List<Integer> cats = goodsList.stream()
                              .flatMap(c->Stream.of(c.getFirstCategoryID(),c.getSecondCategoryID()))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a single stream if my second field is a stream of same type that is being collected i.e. Integer in this example? Basically my final stream would have an Integer from `FirstCategoryID` and then all Integers from `SecondCategoryIDList` for each goods